# UPDATE query - @

Tags: mysql

I need to perform the recursive call to the same table named organisation_smd table.

I have 4 data fields.
1. organisation_id
2. Organisation_type
3. parent_organisation_id (it is another organisation_id in the same table)
4. primary_organisation_id (currently its value is null)

I need to find and update primary_organisation_id value with organisation_id which has organisation_type ='PRIMARY_MERCHANT'.

```
update organisation_smd os1 
    inner join (
                select organisation_id 
                from organisation_smd 
                where organisation_type = 'PRIMARY_MERCHANT'
                and organisation_id = os1.organisation_parent_id
                ) as os2 
set os1.primary_organisation_id = os2.organisation_id 
where os1.organisation_id='6bc7c29d664c4f1eb3cb96b1e573b2ed';
```

How could I achieve this? I want organisation_parent_id inside sub_query to get my desired output.

Comment: What is "this"? Is there any problem with the given query? If yes, share the table structure, sample input data, the expected output and **all** of your attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join needs an `ON` clause, something like:

```
on os2.organisation_id = os1.organisation_parent_id
```

which you have inside the subquery in the `WHERE` clause but you must remove it, so maybe you want this:

```
update organisation_smd os1 
inner join (
  select organisation_id 
  from organisation_smd 
  where organisation_type = 'PRIMARY_MERCHANT'
) as os2 on os2.organisation_id = os1.organisation_parent_id
set os1.primary_organisation_id = os2.organisation_id 
where os1.organisation_id='6bc7c29d664c4f1eb3cb96b1e573b2ed';
```